# Was Jeremiah alive during the rebuilding of the temple?

Tags: tanach, beis-hamikdash, yirmiyahu--book-of

Was Jeremiah alive during the rebuilding of the temple? Please cite your sources.

Answer (score 8):

[Shalshelet HaKabbalah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&st=&pgnum=244&hilite=) writes that ‘they’ say that Yirmeyahu was stoned to death in Egypt, by the Jewish refugees who had brought him there against his will.

[I think it’s safe to assume that this event took place long before the rebuilding of the Temple.]

Comment: Where the roughly chronological order of bible gotten

Comment: @shlomoshetrit The classical text is [Seder Olam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_Olam_Rabbah)

Comment: In 3346 which was 8 years after the חורבן, Nevuchadnetzar conquered מצרים, turning the land into wasteland, as it would stay for the next 40 years. 
Many of the exiles of יהודה were also killed, besides ירמיהו and ברוך בן נריה and a handfull of their followers, who according to one opinion (עי' רש"י קהלת יב-ו בסוף) were taken to בבל where they joined their brethren. According to another opinion ירמיהו died and was buried in מצרים (עי' אישי תנ"ך עמ' רלה בשם מדרש אגדה בראשית ל-טו עיי"ש).

Answer (score 7):

Apparently (according to Wikipedia) the date & place of Jeremiah's death is not documented in classical sources.

However, we are taught that the 2nd temple was built with the guidance of the Anshei Knesset HaGedola - an institution that included - at the time - prophets such as Chagai, Malachi & Zecharia.

Source: Talmud, [Zevachim 62a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Chosen_Temple.2.4?lang=he&p2=Zevachim.62a.6&lang2=bi&w2=Rashi&lang3=he):

> אמר רבה בר בר חנה א"ר יוחנן שלשה נביאים עלו עמהם מן הגולה אחד שהעיד להם על המזבח ואחד שהעיד להם על מקום המזבח ואחד שהעיד להם שמקריבין אף על פי שאין בית. ‏
>
> Rabba bar bar Ḥana says that Rabbi Yoḥanan says: Three prophets ascended with them from the exile: One who testified to them about the size and shape of the altar, and one who testified to them about the proper location of the altar, and one who testified to them that one sacrifices offerings even if there is no Temple, provided that there is a proper altar.

Rashi ibid:

> שלשה נביאים - חגי זכריה ומלאכי:‏

Had Jeremiah been alive, he surely would have been included in this illustrious list. It seems he was not involved - or alive - at the time of the rebuilding of the temple.

Comment: Not necessarily a proof. The Midrash ([Shir Hashirim Rabbah 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.5.5.1?lang=he)) says that even Baruch ben Neriah, Yirmiyahu's disciple, was too old and weak to make the journey to Eretz Yisrael, even if they had carried him in a litter. That would have applied all the more so to Yirmiyahu himself.

Comment: A little off topic but Yechezkel was the one who instituted Megilat Ester into tanach.

Comment: @MordechaiSchmerler Are you sure? Yechezkel's final prophecy is dated around 15 years after the destruction of the First Temple. The story of Megillat Esther is traditionally dated to the very end of the seventy years of Exile. (If you identify Achashverosh with Xerxes than it's even later, around 40 years after the Second Temple was already built.)

Comment: You are correct. I looked into it and I see that I made a mistake. Thank you for helping me.